# Update php version on amazon ec2 ubuntu from 5.3.2 to 5.3.x with chef recipe

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, version, chef-infra

the current php version on the box is

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 19 2012 01:35:33)
```

I changed the default.rb in the chef/cookbooks/php/attributes the following way

```
default['php']['install_method'] = 'source'
```

from 'package', and

```
default['php']['version'] = '5.3.10'
```

I've tried the last one with 5.3.5, .6, .9 as well.

The only affect I can see is in the knife deploy log:

```
INFO: Processing remote_file[/var/chef/cache/php-5.3.10.tar.bz2] action create (php::source line 43)
```

So at least the config gets used, but no matter what I change, PHP stays at the version mentioned above.

Comment: commented the two 'not_if "which php"' lines in source.rb, it is installing now, I'll see what happens

Comment: after 'Chef Run complete in 2324.510432 seconds', php version is still 5.3.2 ...

Comment: there is also php-5.3.10 dir with proper contents in /var/chef/cache, so it was definitely doing something

Comment: Looks like a night's sleep helped the amazon box. I am getting this now for php -v `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/curl.so'`, same for gd.so, mysql.so, mysqli.so, pdo.so, pdo_mysql.so. But, least `PHP 5.3.10 (cli) (built: Jun 20 2012 16:40:55)`. phpinfo() still returs 5.3.2 though...